# Using Gem volume breaks for native dependency updates in docker compose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-compose, rubygems

When running multiple ruby services in a docker compose and sharing the gem volume, updates that require native extensions will break when the base image updates them

Let's say we have a docker-compose file like this:

```
(...)
services:
  ruby_service_1:
    (...)
    volumes:
    - gems_volume:/usr/local/bundle
  ruby_service_2:
    (...)
    volumes:
    - gems_volume:/usr/local/bundle
   (...)
```

This is a pattern I've seen in a lot of guides when dealing with multiple ruby services. The issue is, when the base image updates (which happens for example if you bump the version of the official ruby image), I get an error that it can't find the .so files for gems with native bindings. The solution to this is to remove the volume with `docker compose down --volumes`.
Is there a better way of doing this, or is this something you just need to deal with when using a shared volume for gems?

Thanks,
Finn

Comment: I wouldn't use a shared volume for gems.  Each image should contain its own library dependencies.  There's several reasons to avoid a volume here (could lead to conflicts between the different applications, hard to update, inconsistent results if run on different machines).  Just deleting the `volumes:` blocks you show should be enough to make things work, including seeing updates on rebuilds.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the use of volumes does not have impressive advantages here for Ruby bundles. The meaning of Docker isolation is lost

Probably you don't quite need such volumes. But as option, you can define different volumes for different services

```yaml
services:
  ruby_service_1:
    volumes:
      - ruby_service_1_gems:/usr/local/bundle
  ruby_service_2:
    volumes:
      - ruby_service_2_gems:/usr/local/bundle
volumes:
  ruby_service_1_gems: # Define the named volume for ruby_service_1
  ruby_service_2_gems: # Define the named volume for ruby_service_2
```

With this approach, each service's gems are isolated, reducing the risk of conflicts when updating the base Ruby image